# How to cast a Java.Lang.Enum to an integer?

Tags: java, xamarin.android

In monodroid, i have a java binding which returns a Java.Lang.Enum object.

When i try to cast this object into an int it throws.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
```

Here is what i get in the immediate window of the debugger:

```
state
{OPENING}
base: {Java.Lang.Enum}
IsClosed: false
IsOpened: false
ThresholdClass: 0x1d200832
ThresholdType: {System.MonoType}
```

I am surprised that an enum can not be converted into an int ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [java.lang.Enum.ordinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) to return an int value which represents the position of the Enum constant within the definition of the Enum class for that type of object.

For example, if the definition of the Enum class was something like this:

```
enum Example {
    Cat, Dog, Fish, Goat
}
```

then `Cat.ordinal()` would return int value 0, `Dog.ordinal()` would return int value 1, `Fish.ordinal()` would return int value 2, and so on.

However, the ordinal position of an Enum constant is not guaranteed to stay the same, so this should never be used without being certain that a change in the Enum definition (which would change the ordinal values) won't break your code.

Comment: The cases where you would use an integer constant in other languages can often take an enum in Java without any conversion.  It is worth 2-3 hours to look at a basic enum tutorial and see fundamental things you can do with them.

Comment: I agree. If possible, avoid ever referring to the ordinal positions of Enum constants. (Sadly I know nothing about Monodroid, so I don't know how able it is to make use of Java patterns.)

Comment: @Arkanon: I would expect the enum ordinals to be 0-indexed, so `Cat.ordinal()` would be `0` and `Fish.ordinal()` would be `2`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You are right. I've corrected the answer above so that the indices begin at zero.